# Why ocamlc says I mismatched {} while I don't?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have written `myPercolation.ml`.

```
open MyUnionFind

module type MyPercolationSig = sig
  type percolation
  val create_percolation : int -> percolation
  val open_site : percolation -> int -> int -> unit
  val is_open : percolation -> int -> int -> bool
  val is_full : percolation -> int -> int -> bool
  val can_percolates : percolation -> bool
end

module MyPercolation : MyPercolationSig = struct

  exception IndexOutOfBounds;;

  type percolation = 
      {n : int; 
       sites: bool array; 
       union : MyUnionFind.union_find};;

  let create_percolation n = 
    {n = n; sites = Array.make (n*n) false; union = MyUnionFind.create_union (n*n)};;

  let open_site p i j = 
    let {n;_;union} = p 
    in 
    if not (is_open p i j) then
      begin 
    sites.(index_of n i j) <- true;
    if i - 1 >= 1 && i - 1 <= n && is_open n (i-1) j then
      MyUnionFind.union union (index_of n i j) (index_of n (i-1) j)
    else  if i + 1 >= 1 && i + 1 <= n && is_open n (i+1) j then
      MyUnionFind.union union (index_of n i j) (index_of n (i+1) j)
    else  if j - 1 >= 1 && j - 1 <= n && is_open n i (j-1) then
      MyUnionFind.union union (index_of n i j) (index_of n i (j-1))
    else  if j + 1 >= 1 && j + 1 <= n && is_open n i (j+1) then
      MyUnionFind.union union (index_of n i j) (index_of n i (j+1))
      end;;

  let index_of n i j = n * (i - 1) + j;;

  let is_open {n;sites;_} i j = 
    if i < 1 || i > n || j < 1 || j > n then 
      raise IndexOutOfBounds
    else 
      sites.(index_of n i j);;

  let is_full {n;_;union} i j =
    let rec is_connected_top j' =
      if j = 0 then false
      else 
    if MyUnionFind.is_connected union (index_of n i j) (index_of n 0 j') then true
    else is_connected_top (j'-1)
    in is_connected_top n;;

  let can_percolates p =
    let {n;_;_} = p 
    in  
    let rec is_full_bottom j =
      if j = 0 then false
      else 
    if is_full p n j then true
    else is_full_bottom (j-1)


end
```

---

Please ignore the package `MyUnionFind` package. It is just a homemade implementation for `union-find` algorithm.

when I try to compile the `myPercolation.ml`, I got such an error:

```
$ ocamlc -c myPercolation.ml
File "myPercolation.ml", line 25, characters 11-12:
Error: Syntax error: '}' expected
File "myPercolation.ml", line 25, characters 8-9:
Error: This '{' might be unmatched
```

I think the error is talking about `let {n;_;union} = p` in function of `let open_site p i j`.

I have read through that line and all code many times, but I still don't see any mismatched `{}` in that line.

**can anyone help please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `let {n; _; union} = p` is not well formed OCaml. I think what you want is `let {n; union} = p`. The way to handle fields you don't care about in a record pattern is not to mention them.

**Update**:

As rgrinberg points out, a much better way to describe the problem is that the `_` has to appear as the last field. That's why the compiler is expecting to see `}` afterward. It might be good style to include the `_` as an indicator that you're purposely matching only a subset of the fields of the record. You can, in fact, turn on a compiler option that checks for this.

**Update 2**:

The warning for incomplete record patterns is warning number 9, and also is associated with the letter R. Here's how to use R:

```
$ ocaml -w +R
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# type r = { a: int; b: char };;
type r = { a : int; b : char; }
# let {a} = {a=3; b='x'} in a;;
Warning 9: the following labels are not bound in this record pattern:
b
Either bind these labels explicitly or add '; _' to the pattern.
- : int = 3
```

The command-line syntax is the same for the compiler.

Comment: `{n; union}` will give a compiler warning I think. If you think the compile warning is unnecessary you can use `{n; union; _}` but the underscore must be last.

Comment: I don't see any warning with default settings of OCaml 4.00.0. But you're right, `_` is allowed if it's the last field.

Comment: The warnings must be enabled I think. See: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual021.html#toc78

Comment: I have to admit it would probably be a good discipline to enable these warnings. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible error: `{n;_;_}` should be `{n;_}` Only 1 underscore is necessary. Think of it like the `_` wildcard in a match statement.